# enriching with previous references

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to use the enrichment feature with an existing app.

When reading an (aggregated) feed from the client using a **user_session** I get a response:

```
{
   "results": [
      {
         "activities": [
            {
               "actor": "User:67",
               "foreign_id": "Saving:d6",
               "id": "f1",
               "object": "Item:23",
               "origin": "activities:57",
               "target": "List:82",
               "time": "2018-11-15T09:29:25.291000",
               "verb": "save"
            }
         ],
         ...
```

Now, I would like to have the **67th User** data embed in the response, using the enrichment feature. I tried, using the ruby framework:

```
STREAM_CLIENT.collections.upsert('User', [{id: '67', first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}])
```

However, reading the feed again, the response json does not contain my user data.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 1):

The references that are part of the activity are not the correct format. You should use `client.collections.createUserReference` like described here: https://getstream.io/docs/#frontend_backend_references

Comment: does it mean that all previous activities cannot be linked to Users ?

Comment: You can update activities using update_activities https://getstream.io/docs/#activity-update, but if you already have a a lot of activities this is probably not really feasible.

Comment: yay I already have me feeds full activities in production. This enrichment feature looked real cool ! disappointed it only works for new app...